# What was the possible mistake by Lucifer?

Tags: plot-explanation, lucifer

At the end of Lucifer S03E17, Lucifer says the line,

> I think I've made a horrible mistake

What was the possible mistake?

Answer (score 4):

Lucifer and detective were trying to capture murdered targeting couples. 
At the end he see another detective talking to "his" detective and feel jealous.

Ale the lyrics to song that Skye Townsend sing goes

> An unfamiliar fire’s been burning
>   And I don’t how to feel

and

> I’m not great at love, but I’m open
>   And out of all of the prayers out there, mine was chosen

So in summary Lucy realize that

> He fell in love with a human women.

Comment: I don't understand. How is this news to either the audience or to Lucifer? Wait, so, what's (possibly) the mistake?

Comment: He's in love, he's jealous. There is nothing that elevate him above mortals. Also immortal feeling in love with mortal always end in only one side dying.

Comment: And thats why Amenadiel says that if Satan can find it (the being who weakens him) then Cain can too